# Is it possible to pass variables between Javascript and Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have created a Google Apps Script Project including a Javascript script (as an HTML file as per Google Dev Best Practices). I do some simple arithmetic based on the location of click events within an HTML image input.

Is there any way to pass the numerical values from Javascript to the 
Google Apps Script? If not, can I simply rewrite the functions in the Google Apps Script? (the functions are pretty simple and connected to html elements)

Comment: You need to use the `google.script.run.functionName()` client side API.  From the code editor, click the "Help" menu, and then click "Documentation."  Search "google.script"

Comment: This applies if I rewrite the functions in the Google script, right?

Comment: Please read the documentation and learn some basic information, and make an attempt to implement it.  You need to understand the basic concepts, terms and some details to even ask a valid question.

Comment: I did some reading this past day, and I think I understand what I need to do.